# Deploying Spring application to MCF fails with CFI, works with vmc

Tags: eclipse, spring, deployment, cloud-foundry

Using CloudFoundry Integration for Eclipse (I'm running 32-bit Eclipse 4.2), I consistently get the following error when I attempt to deploy any Spring application to a MCF running on VMware Fusion 5.0.1 on OSX 10.7.4:

```
Communication with server failed: 500 Internal Server Error
```

in the Servers view when I attempt to start the service.

In VMC, the application is visible, with status STOPPED. If I try and start it using VMC, I get

```
maguro:Desktop darrellberry$ vmc start testserver4
Staging Application 'testserver4': .............................................HTTP exception: RestClient::RequestTimeout:Request Timeout
```

If however I export the application as a WAR file from Eclipse and push it onto the MCF using VMC (rather than from within Eclipse), it deploys and starts without error.

All help appreciated!

D

Comment: hi Darrell, is your problem solved?

Answer (score 1):

can you run this command to get more detailed error:

```
vmc logs testserver4 [--all]
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a network connectivity problem. Check the network settings of your Eclipse installation.